# Is there a correspondence between $\operatorname{Spec}K[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/\operatorname{Gal}(K/k)$ and $\operatorname{Spec}k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

The prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ are $(0)$ and $(x-a)$ for $a\in\mathbb{C}$.

Similarly, the prime ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ are $(0)$, $(x-a)$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $(x^2+ax+b)$ for an irreducible quadratic.

This suggests that we can see $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}[x]$ as the quotient of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x]$ by the action of the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$.

The same correspondence holds for $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, I think.

**I would like to know then under what conditions we have a bijection correspondence between $\operatorname{Spec}k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ and $\operatorname{Spec}K[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/\operatorname{Gal}(K/k)$ for a field extension $K/k$. If we have such a bijection, is it also a homeomorphism for the Zariski topology?**

My attempts of proof seem to suggest that we need $K/k$ to be Galois, but I am not sure.

Comment: @AndresMejia, this isn't exactly what I am saying. For each non-zero prime ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ we can associate either a real number or a pair of non-real conjugate complex numbers. This is surely a bijection. What I am not still sure is that it is a homeomorphism when we endow the spectra with Zariski's topology.

Comment: Ah i understand now. Thanks, I’ll delete my comment

Comment: I like "Speck" in the title (and otherwise).

Comment: I've replaced the \text{Spec} TeX with \operatorname{Spec} which will give the correct spacing. Please be mindful of this in the future to avoid loose "speck"s running around :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bijection does indeed require $K/k$ to be Galois. Let's check out our favorite example of a non-Galois extension, $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb Q[\sqrt[3]{2}]$. The Galois group of this extension is trivial, so the quotient of $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Q[\sqrt[3]{2}][x]$ by the Galois action is just $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Q[\sqrt[3]{2}][x]$ again. But this is not in bijection with $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Q[x]$ in the natural way - for instance, the ideal $(x^3-2)$ has two distinct preimages: $(x-\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $(x^2+\sqrt[3]{2}x+\sqrt[3]{2})$.

When $K/k$ is Galois, this is in fact an isomorphism of schemes and thus automatically a homeomorphism for the Zariski topology. The proof is that $(K[x_1,\cdots,x_n])^{Gal}\cong k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ as rings, where $Gal$ is the Galois group, and that $(\operatorname{Spec} A)/G \cong \operatorname{Spec} A^G$ for a nice group $G$ acting on an affine scheme (the Galois group is such a nice group).

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. Do you have some references for these facts?

Comment: Which facts do you refer to?

Comment: Mainly that $(K[x_1,\dotsc,x_n])^{Gal}\cong k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ and that $(\operatorname{Spec} A)/G\cong \operatorname{Spec} A^G$.

Comment: The first one simply follows from $K^{Gal} = k$

Comment: The first is exactly the same as $K^{Gal}=k$: just run that proof term-by-term on the coefficients of the polynomial. The second is a little slippery: the isomorphism is only guaranteed in the (commonly available) literature for finite groups $G$. Morally, since the Galois group only has finite elements, a fix should be available via some sort of group as the limit of it's finite subgroups construction, but I don't have a reference immediately available.

Comment: @KReiser : for the second one, there's also the question of showing that the underlying space of $(\mathrm{Spec} A)/G$ (as a scheme or affine scheme) is the quotient of the underlying space of $\mathrm{Spec} A$ by $G$. I don't know a lot of algebraic geometry so maybe it's easy, but it's not immediately clear to me

Comment: @Max this is not too hard: for any prime ideal defined over $k$, once we extend scalars to $K$ the ideal factors as a product of prime ideals, and these exactly form an orbit under the Galois action (clearly their product is invariant under the Galois action, so it splits as a union of orbits, but if there were multiple orbits then you'd get a contradiction to the primality of the original ideal). This is again something that can be checked in a finite extension - just take the finite extension containing all the scalars involved in the generators of the primes lying over the original ideal.